# How to create a correct apt/sources.list for Debian hppa?

Tags: debian, apt

Until 2020 I used this, and works fine

```
http://debian-stable.parisc-linux.org/debian-hppa buster main contrib non-free
```

now the site give 404.

I don't found any hppa debian repository anywhere for stable, so I want to try unstable.

I found this site

http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian-ports/dists/unstable/

but if I configure apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian-ports/debian-hppa unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian-ports/debian-hppa unstable main contrib non-free
```

give me this error

```
E: The repository 'http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian-ports/debian-hppa unstable Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I have tried to substitute debian-hppa with hppa, but give same error.
They had the debian hppa .deb packages, as this package link for example returns OK: http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports/pool-hppa/main/d/d52/d52_3.4.1-1.1_hppa.deb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `debian-hppa` part of the URL entirely:

```
deb http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian-ports unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian-ports unstable main contrib non-free
```

However you should really [use the CDN](https://www.ports.debian.org/mirrors):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports unstable main contrib non-free
```

You might also need to retrieve the current archive key, as [indicated in the archive instructions](https://www.ports.debian.org/archive):

```
wget -O - https://www.ports.debian.org/archive_2022.key | apt-key add -
```